# Авторизация с помощью google и запись пользователя в fireBase DataBase

Tags: java, android, firebase

Коллеги, такая проблема. 
Авторизую пользователей с помощью google sign in. Далее мне нужно достать емаил, имя и по возможности фото пользователя и записать все это в БД fireBase.

Класс авторизации

public static final int SIGN_IN_CODE = 777;

```
private GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;
private ActivityMainBinding binding;
private GoogleSignInOptions googleSignInOptions;
private DatabaseReference dataBaseUsers;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);

    googleSignInOptions = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestEmail()
            .build();

    googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .enableAutoManage(this, this)
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, googleSignInOptions)
            .build();

    //verification method is user authorized
    authorizationCheck();

    binding.buttonGoogle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(googleApiClient);
            startActivityForResult(intent, SIGN_IN_CODE);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

}

//verification of authorization on the google side
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == SIGN_IN_CODE) {
        GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
        handleSignInResult(result);
    }
}

//verification of authorization result
private void handleSignInResult(GoogleSignInResult result) {
    if (result.isSuccess()) {
        GoogleSignInAccount googleSignInAccount = result.getSignInAccount();

        String mEmail = googleSignInAccount.getEmail();// Вытягиваем емаил, который получили при авторизации
        Users users = new Users();
        users.setEmail(mEmail);

        dataBaseUsers.child(mEmail).setValue(users); // помещаем емаил в БД 

        goMapScreen();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, R.string.not_log_in, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

//method of transition to another activity
private void goMapScreen() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ScreenMapActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

//verification method is user authorized
public void authorizationCheck(){
    if(GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(getApplicationContext()) != null){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ScreenMapActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

}

Сейчас все ок, авторизация проходит успешно. Я могу проверить войдя в профиль пользователя. Только вот кроме самой записи в БД firebase. Новый, авторизованный пользователь, не попадает в БД. Ну и конечно я не могу проверить, вытягиваю ли я email или нет.

Коллеги, прошу не ругаться сильно если что не так. Только изучаю android. Прошу помочь разобраться а лучше показать на примере. Спасибо.

Comment: Вы указали права запись в саму БД? При авторизации создается новый пользователь на вкладке авторизации Firebase?

Comment: @Ivan Vovk Нет. Не создавался. Я нашел проблему. У меня не была реализована авторизация в самой fireBase. Пользователь не попадал в firebase и за-за этого я не могу вытянуть его данные в бд.
Сейчас проблему решил.